# npm install in TFS build throws "not found: git"

Tags: node.js, tfs, npm, npm-install

I installed Git for windows and node.js, they are both on the system's variable "Path" and available.

[image]

I have packages.json file in project and there is TFS build step definition to call it like this :

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="npm install" /> 
</Target>
```

When i go to TFS server and execute "npm install" in my project directory all the packages are set up correctly.

When TFS executes "npm install" during build process i get this error:

EXEC (0, 0)

not found: git

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue with Bamboo. 
TFS is running as a service and the service account's PATH may be different than what you're seeing here. 
If you can , log in to the TFS user's account and adjust the "User Variables"
to include you path to Git. The application is likely taking the "user path variable" instead of combining the "user" and "system" paths.

[image: system vars]

Comment: this error gone somehow when i cleared npm cache. anyway thx for your response!